# react native firebase authentication emulator error message thrown : Error: A network error

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I am attempting to use the recently released firebase emulator suite. specifically the authentication emulator.

I have the emulator installed and have created an test user in the auth emulator. as follows: [image]

Within my code I have:

```
if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  console.log("setup.js: initializing firebase....")
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099/');
} else {
  firebase.app(); // if already initialized, use that one
}
```

to utilized the emulator for authentication. alas I get the following network error:

[image]

Has anyone had success utilizing the firebase emulator suite with react native?